# Eloquent - Get Model with relationship as boolean

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

My Model has the following `one-to-many` relationship

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function likes(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CommentLike::class);
    }
}
```

In my `Controller` I want to get all `Comments` alongside with a boolean value which indicates if the current user exists in the `likes` table

```
$result = Comment::with(['user', 'likes' => function($q) use($user){
  $q->where('user_id', $user->id);
}])
  ->withCount('likes')
  ->where('post_id', $postId)
  ->get();
```

Currently the above query will return the correct result alongside with a row from the likes table if the user is found.

I'm looking for a proper way to return a boolean  value to indicate if the user has liked the comment instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can find how many likes does user make to the comment, in this way.

```
$likes = Comment::whereHas(['likes' => function($q) use ($user){
          $q->where('user_id', $user->id);
         })->where('post_id', $postId)->count();
```

Then using `$likes` variable value, you can conditionally create a boolean value and assign to new variable or same `$likes` variable.

```
$hasLike = $likes ? true : false;
```

Comment: `$hasLike = $likes ? true : false;` is better written this way : `$hasLike = (bool)$likes;` or `$hasLike = !!$likes;` If writing ternary conditions such as `$condition ? true : false` can be avoided then avoid it.

Comment: Or event better `$hasLike = Comment::whereHas(['likes' => function($q) use ($user){
          $q->where('user_id', $user->id);
         })->where('post_id', $postId)->count() > 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `withExists()` method. It's not one of the best documented ones, but I think it's quite simple.

In your example:

```php
$result = Comment::with(['user', 'likes' => function($q) use($user){
        $q->where('user_id', $user->id);
    }])
    ->withCount('likes')
    ->where('post_id', $postId)
    ->get();
```

Consider changing it to:

```php
$result = Comment::with(['user', 'likes'])
    ->withCount('likes')
    ->withExists(['likes' => function ($query) use ($user) {
        $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
    }])
    ->where('post_id', $postId)
    ->get();
```

Result model will contain additional bool property `likes_exists` where `true` means that `$user` liked the comment and `false` means that they didn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I achieved this

in my model.php file

```
public function likedByCurrentUser(){
        return $this->hasOne(Like::class, "tweet_id", "id")
            ->where("user_id", auth()->user()->id);
    }
```

`likedByCurrentUser` method will either return `null` if no rows match else it will return an eloquent object. So in the controller method we can do something like below to get a boolean.

In the controller method by using [withExists](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions)

```
$tweets = TweetModel::with(["user", "likes", "comments.user"])
            ->withExists([
                "likedByCurrentUser as liked_by_current_user" => function($result){
                    return $result === null;
                }
            ])
            ->orderBy("updated_at", "desc")
            ->get();

        return response()->json([
            "tweets" => $tweets
        ]);
```